# visual studio compiled app is not working on xp

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, runtime

I have two desktop applications (lets say 'x' and 'y'). Both written with visual studio 2008 vb.net language. Both have same references, same all settings (checked step by step), both compiled on the same machine (w7), but and only one ('x') is working on all other machines (and w7 and xp) the other ('y') working only on w7. What did I miss? I get error ('y') on xp such us `An unhandled exception ('System.InvalidOperationException') occurred in OVA.exe [4020]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.` 
As I said settings are identical (except name and source location differs by couple folders). Just-In-Time debugging is enabled. I even commented all the code in application 'y', left just forms with no events handling.

Comment: i guess your shortcode `w7` refers to `Windows 7` and `xp` refers to `Windows XP`, right?

Comment: is target framework also the same? Try logging [unhandled exception](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions) it might help you.

Comment: yes, target framework also the same

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx

```
"The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state."
```

Seeing as you commented out the event handlers leaving just the forms.  It might be the initialization of one of the controls.  Or are you doing anything special in the New() function?  If so could you paste that here?

Comment: Problem was interesting: xp machine did not like form's icon. I removed used icon, set the default one - all went perfect.